# How to completely hide bootstrap modal after getting ajax response

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, response

```
// From Ctp
hcp_btn.on('click', function(){
    var value = hcp_field.val();
        if(value != '')
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax_url+'users/add_hcp_type/'+value,
                success:function(response)
                {
                    if(response == 'exist')
                    {
                        $("#hcp_error").show();
                        hcp_btn.addClass('disabled');
                    }
                    else{
                        $("#hcp_type_modal").modal('hide');
                        $("#hcp_type").html(response);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

// For Controller
$this->autoRender = false;
$this->layout = 'ajax';
$this->viewPath = 'Elements';
$this->render('hcp_types');


![This type of background left after modal close in ajax success function][1]
```

I am using cakephp and rendering an element using ajax and dynamically loading data inside the ctp. But after getting ajax response inside ajax success function i am trying to close bootstrap modal nut modal is not completely close some transparent background is left.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to clean the left background

```
//when hidden
$('#hcp_type_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
 $('.modal-backdrop').remove(); 
});
```

Comment: Where i have to put this code ... in my element or in ctp where element is rendered or after this $("#hcp_type_modal").modal('hide');

Comment: you can put it before start of ajax

Comment: As you suggest i place the code before ajax start.. before $.ajax() function but still the problem is there..

Comment: place it before hcp_btn.on('click', function(){

Comment: Not Working...Problem is still there

Comment: as you told i place your code  before hcp_btn.on('click', function(){ 
but this is not working.. modal close but transparent background still left

Comment: i am asking wat code you pasted, you have to change #modal according to your modal id  so it would be #hcp_type_modal instead of #modal

Comment: Yes, i know about this i changed according to my modal id..but this is not working.

Comment: try `$('#hcp_type_modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) { 
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
});`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64932/discussion-between-yash-and-abhishek).